# Is it possible to build a ribbon dynamically, without using external files?

Tags: winapi, ribbon

I would like to know whether it is possible build a ribbon without being forced to use an external application (namely, uicc.exe) for compiling an .xml file into a .bml one, etc. In other words, is there any way to build a ribbon dynamically as it is the case with menus?

Comment: Not with the WIndows Ribbon Frmaework, alas (at least not to my knowledge; if there is a way I wouldn't know it but would love to know). MFC's ribbon allows you to do this (and CMFCVisualStyleWindows7 is almost an exact lookalike of the Windows 7 one, though there is no Windows 8/10 one yet (there is an issue on the Visual Studio public issue tracker about it)), as do many third party alternatives... I've wanted to build one of my own, but that'll happen far into the future. Good luck.

Comment: @andlabs Thanks for your comment and thanks for letting me know that I'm not the only one interested in such a capability.

Comment: [Here's that MFC issue I mentioned, for what it's worth.](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/12835335-improve-mfc-add-a-visualmanager-cmfcvisualmanag)

Comment: @andlabs I think that your comments qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Ribbon Framework of Windows uses always the [IUIFramework::LoadUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd371471(v=vs.85).aspx) method to load the ribbon definition from the resource of your .exe file.

So, if you want to use a dynamic ribbon definition, you could use a external program loader of your .exe program:

1. Create the .xml ribbon markup dynamically.
2. Compile the .xml file with uicc.exe to the .bml file.
3. [Update the resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms648008(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources) of your .exe program.
4. Start your .exe program.

To compile the .xml file at runtime, you could enclose the uicc.exe into your program loader and save it inside the temp folder to execute it.

Indeed this solution is **VERY** bad, but it should work, I believe (I didn't test it). And this solution can be used before starting your .exe program only.